# How may I sort vectors for one vector by another vector?

Tags: r, sorting

suppose I have two vectors; I want to sort x by y so that they are dependent:

```
> x
[1] 1 5 2
> y
[1] 4 5 1
```

I want the results of y is `1,5,4`; so that the smallest value of y is in the first place because the smallest value of x is in first place.

Another example will be

```
> x
[1] 1 5 7 3 4 2
> y
[1] 4 5 6 2 6 8
> sort(y)[order(x)]
[1] 2 8 6 6 4 5
```

the above solution seems not work because the largest value in x is in the third place, but the largest value in sorted y is in the third place.

Comment: I don't understand the logic here.  Are you sorting 'y' based on 'x' order

Comment: Yes, the order of y should be the same as that in x

Comment: But, your result shows the order based on the sorted y

Comment: Because the smallest value in x is in first place, so the samllest value of y should also in first place; the largest value in x is in second palce, so I want to put largest value of y also in second place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rank`

```
sort(y)[rank(x)]
[1] 1 5 4
sort(y1)[rank(x1)]
[1] 2 6 8 5 6 4
```

---

Or do the `order` on the `order`

```
> sort(y)[order(order(x))]
[1] 1 5 4
> sort(y1)[order(order(x1))]
[1] 2 6 8 5 6 4
```

#### data

```
x <- c(1, 5, 2)
y <- c(4, 5, 1)
x1 <- c(1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2)
y1 <- c(4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 8)
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
foo = function(x, y){
    y[match(rank(x, ties.method = "first"), rank(y, ties.method = "first"))]
}
x <- c(1, 5, 2)
y <- c(4, 5, 1)
x1 <- c(1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2)
y1 <- c(4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 8)
foo(x, y)
#[1] 1 5 4
foo(x1, y1)
#[1] 2 6 8 5 6 4
```

Comment: This seems not work for another example:
> x
[1] 1 5 7 3 4 2
> y
[1] 4 5 6 2 6 8
> sort(y)[order(x)]
[1] 2 8 6 6 4 5
The largest value in x is in third place, but the largest value in reordered y is in second place.